# Insert " around HTML attributes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, xhtml, replace

I'd like to insert `"` around attributes that don't have so, by using JavaScript.

For instance:

```
<a class=external title=Title href="http://www.google.com" rel=external>My link</a>
```

Should be replaced with:

```
<a class="external" title="Title" href="http://www.google.com" rel="external">My link</a>
```

Similarly:

```
<a target=_blank href="http://www.google.com">My link</a>
```

Should be replaced with:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">My link</a>
```

Basically - all attributes that don't have `"` should get so.

Any idea? I guess regexp is the way to go?

EDIT: I need to do this, as the HTML is produced by a wysiwyg-editor, in order to be submitted to a CMS. The CMS does only accept valid XHTML.

Comment: No quotes is valid in HTML, why do you want to do this?

Comment: If your html rendered before the script execution, then what the benefit of the script Or if the script runs before the HTML how the script find out the TAGS...

Comment: on DOM ready, you could go for $('body').html($('body').html()); but I'm afraid that would be too much trimming...

Comment: The browser's HTML parser basically does this for you as the page loads if you have neglected it.

Comment: @elclanrs, I need to do this, as the HTML is produced by a wysiwyg-editor, in order to be submitted to a CMS. The CMS does only accept valid XHTML.

Comment: I'd deal with this at the CMS end. You need to run the submitted data through a whitelisting HTML parser to defend against XSS attacks anyway. Have that parser output XHTML when its done.

Comment: Well, I am afraid this is no option, as the CMS is a third party software written in java. Protection etc. is already built into it. It has to be done before the XHTML is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can use jQuery, given a variable `htmlInput` to clean-up, I would give a try to :

```
var cleanHtml = $('<div>'+htmlInput+'</div>').html();
```

see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUq7U/)

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks! But ... this doesn't work in IE - which it has to do.

Comment: @Helge yes, it does not work with IE<9. For those, you may give a try to (the somewhat dated) http://www.stevetucker.co.uk/innerxhtml.htm